# is this json file? and if yes, how can I read it back to java?

Tags: java, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A better Java JSON library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)

Hi,

I have a json file like this:

```
workloads = [
  {
    total: 5,
    attributes:
    {
      taskA:1,
      taskB:2
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please use the search function on this site, that's been asked hundreds of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a valid JSon object.

to validate your json you can use for example [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Have a look at the Json grammar [here](http://www.json.org/)

To know which library you can use to read json from java look here [A better Java JSON library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)

Comment: Thanks. this is what I have been searching for!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of links on the JSON site: http://json.org/java/